# Nginx subfolder app with URL rewrites

Tags: nginx

I have a problem to define proper vhost rules for nginx hosting 2 separate applications. Unfortunately, I can't use subdomain on the host, so I'm stuck with a subfolder approach. The main application is the TYPO3, with the following vhost config:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server; 

    root /var/www/typo3dev/web;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
       }

       location = /robots.txt {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
       }


       # Deny all attempts to access hidden files such as .htaccess, .htpasswd, .DS_Store (Mac).
       location ~ /\. {
                deny all;
                access_log off;
                log_not_found off;
       }

    location ~ \.php$ {
                        try_files $uri =404;
                        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                        fastcgi_index index.php;
                        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
                        fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;
                        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
                        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
                        fastcgi_read_timeout 1200;
        }


        location ~ /\.(js|css)$ {
                expires 604800s;
        }

        if (!-e $request_filename){
                rewrite ^/(.+)\.(\d+)\.(php|js|css|png|jpg|gif|gzip)$ /$1.$3 last;
        }

        location ~* ^/fileadmin/(.*/)?_recycler_/ {
                deny all;
        }
        location ~* ^/fileadmin/templates/.*(\.txt|\.ts)$ {
                deny all;
        }
        location ~* ^/typo3conf/ext/[^/]+/Resources/Private/ {
                deny all;
        }
        location ~* ^/(typo3/|fileadmin/|typo3conf/|typo3temp/|uploads/|favicon\.ico) {
        }

    location ~* ^/qa/.* {
        allow all;
    }

        location / {

                        if ($query_string ~ ".+") {
                                return 405;
                        }
                        if ($http_cookie ~ 'nc_staticfilecache|be_typo_user|fe_typo_user' ) {
                                return 405;
                        } # pass POST requests to PHP
                        if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD)$ ) {
                                return 405;
                        }
                        if ($http_pragma = 'no-cache') {
                                return 405;
                        }
                        if ($http_cache_control = 'no-cache') {
                                return 405;
                        }
                        error_page 405 = @nocache;

                        try_files /typo3temp/tx_ncstaticfilecache/$host${request_uri}index.html @nocache;
        }

        location @nocache {
                        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }
}
```

Now, I want to host a second application in the subfolder of the root of the TYPO3, which is `packagist/packagist/web`. This Packagist app requires a rewrite URL rules to work properly. Its normal vhost config would something like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name yourserver.loc;
    root /var/www/packagist/web;
    index index.php index.html;     

    location / {                
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to rewrite
        try_files $uri @rewriteapp;                
        satisfy any;                        
    }                

    location @rewriteapp {                
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;        
    }    

    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {        
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;              
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;        
        include fastcgi_params;               
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;        
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;                
        internal;    
    }    

    # return 404 for all other php files not matching the front controller
    # this prevents access to other php files you don't want to be accessible.

    location ~ \.php$ {      
        return 404;    
    }    

    error_log /var/log/nginx/packagist_error.log;    
    access_log /var/log/nginx/packagist_access.log;
}
```

How can I merge those 2 configurations? I was trying to add the following to my TYPO3 vhost but the URL rewrite doesn't work.

```
location ^~ /packagist/packagist/web/.* {
                #root /var/www/typo3dev/web/packagist/packagist/web;
                alias /var/www/typo3dev/web/packagist/packagist/web;
                index index.php index.html;

                #try_files $uri $uri/ /packagist/packagist/web/app.php;
                try_files $uri @rewrite;

                location ~ \.php {
                        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
                        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
                        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
                }
        }

    location @rewrite {
                rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
        }
```

At present if I want to use URL e.g. http://example.com/packagist/packagist/web/app.php/register I'm getting 404 page.

Please help :)

Answer (score 0):

This might not solve your issue, but is a clear misconfiguration:

`location ^~ /packagist/packagist/web/.*` does not work in your solution. `^~` is a prefix match that causes nginx not to check regular expressions after the prefix match. So, in this case it matches all requests to URIs starting with literal `/packagist/packagist/web/.*`, and I doubt that you have any requests like that in your application.

You need to use `location ^~ /packagist/packagist/web` to match all requests starting with that prefix.